# nodejs Out Of Memory only when running under forever, mon, upstart etc

Tags: node.js, upstart, forever

I have a node program I've tested tons of times doing nohup command & and it never runs into any memory problems as long as I pass node the `--max_old_space_size=12000` as my process can use up to several GBs.

Now, I've tried running the exact same command with forever, mon, and upstart and the process will always fail with "FATAL ERROR: CodeRange::GetNextAllocationBlock Allocation failed - process out of memory"

Any ideas why this might be happening?  I haven't been able to check the memory usage right before it fails, but it looks like it fails when it reaches only about 3gb of memory.

Comment: So...I just reproduced the problem not running in mon, forever, or upstart so that's not the issue....the only difference between the command I was running without problems and the command I'm running now is that now I'm writing the output to a log file with  >> /root/output.log 2>&1 while the other was piping it to tee....I want to test my old working command one more time just to be sure it still works because it doesn't make sense that that difference would be relevant, does it?

Comment: Which version of node are you using?  If it's a 0.10.33 release, have you tried with 0.11.14?  At this point there's a lot that is getting farther ahead in 0.11.x that you might want to consider it.

Comment: omg, I've been down that road and never going back.  I had HUGE performance and memory problems using the latest node.  Garbage collector was using 99% of processing time, and sometimes garbage wasn't being cleaned up.  Switched back to to the latest stable and all was fixed.  Took me forever to diagnose because it never occurred to me the .11 branch could of had that many problems.  I'm not even blaming node here, looked like a v8 issue but would have never guessed a newer v8 versions would introduce problems like that.  Anyways. I think I found the problem.  Its the --expose-gc option.

Comment: running one last test to be certain, but I think its the --expose-gc option that is causing the problem.  I thought my old working command had that it in it as well but now it seems I may have been mistaken.

Comment: no...I was wrong its not that.  I have no idea what the problem is.  The other day I had it running for days using up 8gb of memory without any problems...

Answer (score 0):

Are you running via any start up script using forever ? If so just , find a way to add a the line  Max old space..

Comment: With forever I'm using forever start -c "node --max_old_space_size=12000" app.js which should pass the commands to node...at first I thought it was forever not working correctly and not passing the arguments...but now I've tried with mon and upstart which lets you specify any command you want and I'm still running into the error...so now I no longer think its forever specific or that node isn't getting the max_old_space_size argument...I can try running it without the max_old_space_size argument and see if it crashes in the same part but why wouldn't mon or upstart run the command specified?

Comment: I too had  this max old space issue in node.. But i cant test it, whether node accepted that space or not? It doesnt shows us anything.. I once tested it with twitter public streaming which get crashed eventhough i gave max old space...  I tested in windows..

Comment: yeah, I've had issues with max-old-space size being seemingly inconsistent.  One thing note is that the 32-bit version of node last I checked had a hard cap no matter what you passed to max_old_space_size and there are also limits in all versions on the size of an individual string so even if you are getting an out of memory error its not neccesarily because of max_old_space_size.